# Remove custom attribute from all <a> element in dynamic HTML container

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How to remove index attribute from all  elements in the variable container.innerHTML.
Html is generated dynamically.

```
var container.innerHTML = test &nbsp;&nbsp; <a class ="test-image-class" index="0" href="" ><span>testimage</span></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
     &nbsp;&nbsp; <a class = "test-image-class" index="1" href="" ><span>testimage</span></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
    these two images are not matching &nbsp;&nbsp; <a class = "test-image-class" index="3" href="" ><span>testimage</span></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy solution can be just replace with regular expression

```
`test &nbsp;&nbsp; <a class ="test-image-class" index="0" href="" ><span>testimage</span></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
     &nbsp;&nbsp; <a class = "test-image-class" index="1" href="" ><span>testimage</span></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
    these two images are not matching &nbsp;&nbsp; <a class = "test-image-class" index="3" href="" ><span>testimage</span></a> &nbsp;&nbsp`.replace(/index="[\d]+"/g, '')
```

Here `replace` is the string replace function for JavaScript it's generally accepts two parameter one search string or regex pattern & replace string. Here `/index="[\d]+"/g` is the pattern `''` is the replace string. `g` is used to match all.

Answer (score 0):

A Regex is the easiest way out of this. The search below uses `index`

```
let str = `test &nbsp;&nbsp; <a class ="test-image-class" index="0" href="" ><span>testimage</span></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp; <a class = "test-image-class" index="1" href="" ><span>testimage</span></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
these two images are not matching &nbsp;&nbsp; <a class = "test-image-class" index="3" href="" ><span>testimage</span></a> &nbsp;&nbsp`;

let re = /index="[^"]*"/gi;
let result = str.replace(re, "");
console.log(result);
```